Unreal first person BP Looses movement input after attached on rail
i got a problem with my game logic that i cant figure out.. so i have two modes in my game, a free roam and an on rail state. On free roam the player would be able to go around freely with keyboard and mouse. On rail mode i got a spline that the first player BP got attached to and goes around till any of the key got pressed it goes back to free roam. the on rail logic works fine
This is the onrail event which attach my firstPerson character on a spline and move it around
as seen on the picture. i also got a widget where the player can select the rail button this is the event on is
This is the on button click event where if the player press the button it triggers the onrail event 
The problem is on the third picture :
This is the problematic part, where if any key got pressed on rail, the game mode goes back to free roam mode
Where i got the any key event if it got triggered i check if the previous game mode was the on rail and if so it set it back to free roam, unhide the crosshair widget set the actor location to the player start location set the input mode to game only  and stop the timeline..  it runs down, but when the player got back to the player start position , it doesn't move anymore.. the mouse look works fine, just the movement input gets ignored somehow.. i set the debug view on and the EnhancedInputAction IA_Move gets triggered, but the character itself doesn't move.. I wonder if anybody here have any suggestion what could be the problem ??
